# Creating recursive Python functions

Tags: python

Q1: Create a recursive Python function that evaluates 4n

here's what I have

```
def multiply(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return 4*n*multiply(n-1)
```

Q2:Write a recursive Python function that returns the sum of the first n integers

here's what I have...

```
def sum_n(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return n + sum_n(n-1)
```

just wanted to know if my codes are correct??

Comment: Have you tried them on a few values? Because I bet if you plugged 7 into that first one you'd be in for a surprise

Comment: Seems some sort of homework

Comment: Homework is fine if they're providing a solution and asking for help. It's not a "do it for me" question. That said, did the asker **try** the solutions?

Comment: If you want to know how to _improve_ your code, try [codereview.se], but if you just want us to grade your work for you, that's not what SO if for. Actually run your code and see if it works.

Comment: both of the codes work but I'm not sure if I am on the right track, especially for the first question

Comment: First code doesn't work.

Comment: @pimpmycamel *Do* they work? They compile, which is indeed a start. I get multiply(7) = 20643840. If that isn't what you expect, then something is not quite right

Comment: First code works for `multiply(2)` did you test it for any other values?

Comment: @JohnLaRooy my unit tests are also typically just n = 2 :) As long as 2 is a randomly chosen value then what is the probability it's the only one that fails out of infinite possible numbers?

Comment: @en_Knight, do you work for Toyota? lol

Answer (score 3):

Your `multiply` can be fixed with a couple of small modifications

```
def multiply(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return 4 + multiply(n - 1)
```

Note it's now identical to your `sum_n` except one `n` has been replaced by the constant `4`

**edit:**

What's the problem with this version?

```
def multiply(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return 4*n*multiply(n-1)
```

Consider the terminating case (n==1), You either have to make this `return 4` or use `n==0` and `return 0` as I have done.

Choosing `n==1` as the terminating case also means that `multiply(0)` fails.

I have trouble guessing what you were thinking in this return path

```
return 4*n*multiply(n-1)
```

It does move the recursive call toward the terminating case (as long as n is a positive integer) by passing n-1, but you should be simply adding 4 to the return result. Consider:

```
multiply(4) == 4 + multiply(3) == 4 + 4 + multiply(2) == 4 + 4 + 4 + multiply(1)
```

**edit2:**

Some people (well at least one) are complaining that this doesn't work for negative integers. This can be handled by adding one more condition that simply flips `n` back to a positive integer.

```
def multiply(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    elif n < 0:
        return -multiply(-n)
    else:
        return 4 + multiply(n - 1)
```

Comment: Wait doesn't work on negative numbers. The op didn't specify but... I took back my upvote until it does :)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, however, I agree with en_Knight, can you please explain what was the problem?

Comment: Okay you can have my upvote back because it works on 2 and this is probably what the question was looking for (though handling negatives would have been more fun). @pimpmycamel please just try plugging a few numbers into yours, it will become clear very quickly that your's is not valid.

Comment: @en_Knight, I added support for negative integers :)

Comment: @JohnLaRooy phew! I can add it to my production code now!

Answer (score 0):

You find out if you code is correct by entering the code somewhere you can run it (for example http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_python_online.php or many others found by asking google python ide online`).

Then you run your code and try different values.

This is an important step in coding, test the code with different possibilities. Its not ok to ask a question like you have on a site to find out. It is ok to ask a question when you have tried it and found an error that you can't figure out how to solve (but make sure you show what you have tried).

But to actually answer your question this time, EDIT-FROM: both do not work as formatted in the question when using python EDIT-TO: They do now compile, I see you picked up on what was wrong and changed which is good to see (have not tested further) EDIT-END. Not tried Python3.

Comment: Hmm the "actual answer" part seems a little sparse. As the OP points out, they *do* compile, so what do you mean? The second one seems fine, and the first one works on n=2 as John points out so I can only assume it works all the time

Comment: The formatting was incorrect causing an compiler error. He has since changed the format so it does now compile. Have not tested for him further.